# troubles with next and previous query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a list and the returned table looks like this. I took the preview of only one car but there are many more.

[image]

What I need to do now is check that the current KM value is larger then the previous and smaller then the next. If this is not the case I need to make a field called Trustworthy and should fill it with either 1 or 0 (true/ false).

The result that I have so far is this:

[image]

validKMstand and validkmstand2 are how I calculate it. It did not work in one list so that is why I separated it.

In both of my tries my code does not work.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
 FullList as (
SELECT
    *
FROM
eMK_Mileage as Mileage
)


, ValidChecked1 as (
SELECT 
        UL1.*,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT TOP(1)UL2.* 
            FROM FullList AS UL2
            WHERE
                UL2.FK_CarID = UL1.FK_CarID AND
                UL1.KM_Date > UL2.KM_Date AND
                UL1.KM > UL2.KM
            ORDER BY UL2.KM_Date DESC
        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS validkmstand
FROM FullList as UL1
)

, ValidChecked2 as (
SELECT 
        List1.*,
        (CASE   WHEN List1.KM > ulprev.KM
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS validkmstand2
FROM ValidChecked1 as List1 outer apply
    (SELECT TOP(1)UL3.* 
            FROM ValidChecked1 AS UL3
            WHERE
                UL3.FK_CarID = List1.FK_CarID AND
                UL3.KM_Date <= List1.KM_Date AND
                List1.KM > UL3.KM
            ORDER BY UL3.KM_Date DESC) ulprev
)

SELECT * FROM ValidChecked2 order by FK_CarID, KM_Date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```
;with data as 
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by fk_carid order by km_date) 
    from eMK_Mileage
)

select 
    d.FK_CarID, d.KM, d.KM_Date, 
    valid = 
       case 
          when (d.KM > d_prev.KM /* or d_prev.KM is null */) 
           and (d.KM < d_next.KM /* or d_next.KM is null */) 
          then 1 else 0 
       end 
from data d
left join data d_prev on d.FK_CarID = d_prev.FK_CarID and d_prev.rn = d.rn - 1
left join data d_next on d.FK_CarID = d_next.FK_CarID and d_next.rn = d.rn + 1
order by d.FK_CarID, d.KM_Date
```

With SQL Server versions 2012+ you could have used the `lag()` and `lead()` analytical functions to access the previous/next rows, but in versions before you can accomplish the same thing by numbering rows within partitions of the set. There are other ways too, like using correlated subqueries.

I left a couple of conditions commented out that deal with the first and last rows for every car - maybe those should be considered valid is they fulfill only one part of the comparison (since the previous/next rows are null)?

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. I had no Idea that I could number the rows like this.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty useful indeed. But using lag/lead it would have been much more clean. Look at this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2253c/1

Comment: Yeah I found some great examples with LAG and LEAD, but I am bound to SQL 2008 here .